# Tag image with custom divs which shall stick to the picture

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to tag some `div`s to an image which shall stay in the right place as the window size changes.

It kind of works, but only until the image looses in height. How do I improve my code to make the markers always stick to the image.

You can perfectly see what I mean running the code in fullscreen.

```css
.container-fluid {
  padding: 5%;
  background-color: #EDEDED;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 60%;
}

.marker {
  position: absolute;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 4px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  &::after {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left: -2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0);
    display: none;
    content: attr(data-after-content);
    width: 150px;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Zuric Light";
  }
  &:hover::after {
    display: block;
  }
}

.marker-one {
  left: 43%;
  top: 12%;
}

.marker-two {
  left: 61%;
  top: 39%;
}

.marker-three {
  left: 49%;
  top: 61%;
}

.marker-four {
  left: 55%;
  top: 77%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid position-relative min-vh-100 d-flex justify-content-center">
  <img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/projektarbeit-interstuhl.appspot.com/o/pure%2Fpure_back_full_red.png?alt=media&token=02cac375-3340-4bc6-bbed-6ada0614a3f9" alt="Pure" class="align-self-center">

  <div class="marker marker-one" data-after-content="Info">
    +
  </div>

  <div class="marker marker-two" data-after-content="Info">
    +
  </div>

  <div class="marker marker-three" data-after-content="Info">
    +
  </div>

  <div class="marker marker-four" data-after-content="Info">
    +
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You need to wrap the images and markers in an **inline-block/flex** element so it shrinks to just the size of the image.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks, but could you please illustrate your answer with the help of my code? I don't really get how to implement your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want a div to stay over top of an image on screen resize. To accomplish this, you can need to set a container around the image, which is set to the 60% width of the page container. Then, set this to position: relative. That way, the hover buttons are positioned using the percent of the total width of that container, not of the whole page.

**New HTML**

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid position-relative min-vh-100 d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/projektarbeit-interstuhl.appspot.com/o/pure%2Fpure_back_full_red.png?alt=media&token=02cac375-3340-4bc6-bbed-6ada0614a3f9" alt="Pure" class="align-self-center">

    <div class="marker marker-one" data-after-content="Info">
      +
    </div>

    <div class="marker marker-two" data-after-content="Info">
      +
    </div>

    <div class="marker marker-three" data-after-content="Info">
      +
    </div>

    <div class="marker marker-four" data-after-content="Info">
      +
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Updated CSS

```
.container-fluid {
  padding: 5%;
  background-color: #EDEDED;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: fit-content !important;
}

.image-container {
    width: 60% !important;
    height: fit-content !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.marker {
  position: absolute;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 4px;
  &::after {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left: -2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    display: none;
    content: attr(data-after-content);
    width: 150px;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Zuric Light";
  }
  &:hover::after {
    display: block;
  }
}

.marker-one {
  left: 38%;
  top: 5%;
}

.marker-two {
  left: 70%;
  top: 36%;
}

.marker-three {
  left: 46%;
  top: 61%;
}

.marker-four {
  left: 55%;
  top: 80%;
}
```

This should work now! Hope it helps!